# Animation Not Running

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I am trying to make a loading screen using CSS Animations. The screen is 4 different bars shrinking and growing. I want to arrange them in this formation where they form a square. I use absolute positioning to position them, but I would like to know if there is a better way. I managed to do 3 bars with display and float but did not manage to do the last one.

Now, the animations are not running at all. Can somebody help me?

Code:
https://codepen.io/ngmh/pen/gxewJK

HTML:

```
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
<div id="left"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#top{
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 12.5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 37.5px;
  animation-name: loading-1;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
#bottom{
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 12.5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 112.5px;
  animation-name: loading-1;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
#left{
  background-color: blue;
  width: 25px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 12.5px;
  animation-name: loading-2;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
#right{
  background-color: green;
  width: 25px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 12.5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 112.5px;
  top: 37.5px;
  animation-name: loading-2;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes loading-1{
  0%:{width: 100px;}
  50%:{width: 10px;}
  100%:{width: 100px;}
}
@keyframes loading-2{
  0%:{height: 100px;}
  50%:{height: 10px;}
  100%:{height: 100px;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be any colon `:` after the percent sign `%` in your `@keyframes` rules

```css
#top{
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 12.5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 37.5px;
  animation-name: loading-1;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
#bottom{
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 12.5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 112.5px;
  animation-name: loading-1;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
#left{
  background-color: blue;
  width: 25px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 12.5px;
  animation-name: loading-2;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
#right{
  background-color: green;
  width: 25px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 12.5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 112.5px;
  top: 37.5px;
  animation-name: loading-2;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes loading-1{
  0% {width: 100px;}
  50% {width: 10px;}
  100% {width: 100px;}
}
@keyframes loading-2{
  0% {height: 100px;}
  50% {height: 10px;}
  100% {height: 100px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
<div id="left"></div>
```

---

Using pseudo elements would make the markup smaller and with that maybe more maintainable.

The `outer` does not use absolute positioning and will flow better with the rest of the content.

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
}
.outer div,
.outer::before,
.outer::after,
.outer div::before,
.outer div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 12.5px;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.outer::before {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  left: 37.5px;
  animation-name: loading-1;
}
.outer::after{
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  top: 112.5px;
  animation-name: loading-1;
}
.outer div::before{
  background-color: blue;
  width: 25px;
  height: 100px;
  animation-name: loading-2;
}
.outer div::after{
  background-color: green;
  width: 25px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 112.5px;
  top: 37.5px;
  animation-name: loading-2;
}
@keyframes loading-1{
  0% {width: 100px;}
  50% {width: 10px;}
  100% {width: 100px;}
}
@keyframes loading-2{
  0% {height: 100px;}
  50% {height: 10px;}
  100% {height: 100px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="outer"><div></div></div>
```